# Traceroute giving wrong country on AWS

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, dns, performance-testing, traceroute

I have an AWS server with availability in EU West (Paris).

IP: 35.180.120.0
Public DNS of server: ec2-35-180-120-0.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com

When using visual Traceroute, the final country shows USA not France.

There also seems to be a large number of hops.

Test results: https://www.monitis.com/traceroute/index.jsp?url=quickbus.com&testId=2439438

[image]

Any ideas Why?

Comment: Read the fine print below the map

Comment: @Mat not helpful!

Answer (score 0):

IP geolocation is hard. This is simply a mistake since hops 13 through 25 are clearly not in the US.

But whatever IP geolocation service monitis is using simply returns a wrong location. It's probably returning a US location because these IPs belong to Amazon and Amazon itself is registered in the US.

If you want better geolocation, use a service like [db-ip](https://db-ip.com/52.46.93.76). They're pretty good.

Also, [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) is right. The fact that the locations are approximate are clearly written in the fine print in the screenshot you posted.